# two-way binding Angularjs bug

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My angular App makes use of multiple controllers and all of them utilize the two-way binding perfectly fine except this one. For some reason it's not updating the scope variables in my angular.extend when I change the variable at a later time. Here's what I do:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    cart: {
        products: [
            {amount: 1, name: 'product 1', total: 4.95},
            {amount: 4, name: 'product 2', total: 4.95},
            {amount: 2, name: 'product 3', total: 4.95},
        ],
        deliveryCost: 0,
        total: 0,
        orderContinue: false,
    }
});
```

And when I want to add a product to the cart I do:

```
addToCart: function(id) {
    var newProduct = {amount: 1, name: 'product 4', total:5.94};
    $scope.cart.products.push(angular.extend(newProduct));
}
```

When I console.log my $scope.cart.products in the addToCart function, it shows the newly added product, but then when I want to have it updated in my view, it just doesn't add the product to the list:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="cartController">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h4>Cart</h4>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="products in cart.products">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{products.amount}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {{products.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The product gets added like this

```
<div ng-controller="cartController" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-lg-2" style="border: 1px solid black;">
     <button ng-click="addToCart(1)">Add to</button>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `angular.extend` here?  For what you are doing, it does not seem necessary.  You should be able to just say `$scope.carts - { cart: .... }` and `$scope.cart.products.push({ ... })`.  My hunch is that your use of angular.extend is not triggering a digest cycle that would result in a view update.

Comment: It's because you have `cartController` declared twice in the HTML - those controller's dont share instances, they each create their own instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have used ng-controller twice in html. so there will be 2 different scope objects for each declaration.
Add following cod inside first controller scope.

```
 <button ng-click="addToCart(1)">Add to</button>
```

If you want to see actually whether there are two different controllers. Just console $scope object in controller. It will be printed twice initially. You can see object id of $scope as

```
console.log($scope.$id);
```

you can see different ids.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use ng-controller directive, a new child scope is created and controller function is instantiated with new $scope. In your case you are using two ng-controllers, thus they will have different $scope. Try writing same code under single ng-controller, it'll work.

For your reference [Angular Docs - Understanding Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)